# Exectuing JS script from file containing c# variables

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I'm creating a software using CefSharp and needs to executes some JS code. What I'm doing for now is to write the script using only one line, but it's not convenient and it makes it hard to apply modifications.

Here is the JS script from file that I tried to execute :
`console.log(size) //size.Text is the variable defined in C#`
But as the `size` variable is defined in c#, the output I get is `undefined`.

Here is the code I use to load the file :

```
string size = "XL";
string testJs = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", "test.js");
string test = File.ReadAllText(testJs);
browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(test);
```

And the one that would work (the one-lined one) :

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded("console.log(" + size + ");")
```

So the main problem is to pass the variable to have `XL` as an output in the console of the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that `size` is passed from C# code, what you need in the js file is a placeholder which later can be replaced.

One possible solution might be -

**JS File**

```
console.log('@{SIZE}@');// you can use any formatting for your placeholder
```

**C# Code**

```
string size = "XL";
string testJs = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"Data\", "test.js");
string test = File.ReadAllText(testJs).Replace("@{SIZE}@", size);
browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(test);
```

This approach will allow you to use as many placeholders as you want in your js file and as many number of places you want to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's the nearest of what I was thinking

Answer (score -1):

Are you passing a view model to a Razor template? If so, you can use razor syntax within script tags:

```cs
<script>
    console.log(@Model.size);
</script>
```